# Which all ports spring cloud consul config app uses for communicating with consul?

Tags: consul, spring-cloud-consul, gossip

As per my understanding the spring cloud consul config is using only port 8500 by default for communicating with consul. If this is correct, Won't this application participate in gossip protocol? If yes, how is it being done?

Answer (score 1):

Spring Cloud Consul is not using gossip protocol, just HTTP API. So you are correct about port 8500.

> Consul provides Service Discovery services via an HTTP API and DNS. Spring Cloud Consul leverages the HTTP API for service registration and discovery. This does not prevent non-Spring Cloud applications from leveraging the DNS interface. Consul Agents servers are run in a cluster that communicates via a gossip protocol and uses the Raft consensus protocol.

http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-consul/2.0.0.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-consul.html#spring-cloud-consul-discovery